# Unity3D - Gear VR Input doesn't work between scenes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, gear-vr

I'm creating a project using the Gear VR, where you can rotate an object and display information based on the swipe and tap controls on the side of the headset.

Everything works great, I can rotate and select stuff when I use the touchpad on the side of the Gear VR, but when I change scenes and return to the main menu, and then go back into the scene I was just on, the functionality stops working.

I am using this script I've made:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class GearVRTouchpad : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject heart;

    public float speed;

    Rigidbody heartRb;

    void Start ()
    {
        OVRTouchpad.Create();
        OVRTouchpad.TouchHandler += Touchpad;

        heartRb = heart.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }  

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Main Menu");
        }
    }


    void Touchpad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var touches = (OVRTouchpad.TouchArgs)e;

        switch (touches.TouchType)
        {
            case OVRTouchpad.TouchEvent.SingleTap:                
                // Do some stuff    
                break;      

            case OVRTouchpad.TouchEvent.Up:
                // Do some stuff
                break;
                //etc for other directions

        }
    }
}
```

I've noticed that when I start my game, an `OVRTouchpadHelper` is created. I don't know if that has anything to do with my problem.

The error I am getting is:

> `MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GearVRTouchpad' has
>   been destroyed but you are still trying to access it. Your script
>   should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the
>   object.`

**BUT** I have not referenced this script anywhere else.

When I check my scene in play mode, the script is still there with the variable assignments still present.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Your error is not in GearVRTouchpad class, its within class that uses GearVRTouchpad. If you could provide those that throw this exception would be nice.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, but I haven't used this script in any other scripts or files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OVRTouchpad.TouchHandler` is a `static EventHandler` (so it will persist through the lifetime of the game).  Your script is subscribing to it when it's created but isn't unsubscribing when it's destroyed.  When you reload the scene the old subscription is still in the event but the old `GearVRTouchpad` instance is gone.  This will result in the `MissingReferenceException` next time the `TouchHandler` event fires.  Add this to your class:

```
void OnDestroy() {
    OVRTouchpad.TouchHandler -= Touchpad;
}
```

Now, whenever a `GameObject` with the `GearVRTouchpad` behaviour is destroyed, the `static` event in `OVRTouchpad` will no longer have a reference to it.

Comment: @Tom Happy to help!